# I got an error with a dkms file

Tags: dpkg, gnome-terminal, secure-boot

So I was trying to fix my obs studio and had a snap version installed from the store and tried installing it from the website simultaneously. When i installed its prerequisite, it started throwing and error. Due to this, I cannot install other apps through the terminal. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2IHZ.png)

it shows that the dpkg file is there, but shows its inactive and when i run `dpkg --configure -a` it shows that the file was inactive.

Can someone help me? Please?

Comment: Included image is the text dialog prior to the MOK enrollment dance.

Answer (score 0):

DKMS is a system for automatically building third party kernel drivers for hardware.

You have secure boot enabled in your bios settings.  Secure boot requires the kernel and all of its drivers to be signed in an attempt at preventing malicious software and drivers from being installed.

To verify that you actually intend the third party driver's installation, you have to enroll an encryption key in your bios.  The dialog you included as an image is the first step to that process.

The next steps are to save a one time password, and then eventually reboot, where it should ask you for that password.

Once that process is successfully completed, your driver should then be able to pass the secure boot signature check and should load at boot.

If the process fails, you can use `dpkg --configure` again to retrigger the process.  If you can't get the MOK enrollment screen to work at boot, there are manual ways to enroll the key as well.

Comment: thanks man i appriciate your help,

Answer (score 0):

Ust <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the `OK`.

Then proceed with MOK.

An easier way is to disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: is disabling secure boot recemmondable?

Comment: It is the easiest solution for this type of issues. Secure Boot is useless. If you aren't using Windows in dual boot, it is 100% useless.

Comment: oh okay thank you